# Why is this equality to another object check in String.java?

Tags: java, string

In String.java, this code is at the beginning of the `.equals()` method:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    // ... check if instance of String, etc.
}
```

Is this check purely for performance reasons (i.e. not including it will check the characters of `this` against itself)?

Comment: `==` check for `hash code` first before comparing the characters. `==` checks the references in the memory if they are same then there is no meaning of comparing the same object to itself.

Comment: *Is this check purely for performance reasons* -- yes. This optimization is probably especially helpful since a lot of strings in Java are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), but since not all strings are interned it can also fall back on the deep (char-by-char) equality comparison.

Comment: == is not a check for hashCode(), though this is not the first time I've seen this idea expressed on SO.   

public static class Thingy
{
  String value;
  public Thingy(String value) { this.value = value; }  
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {return 1;}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Thingy A = new Thingy("A");
   Thingy B = new Thingy("B");
   System.out.println("A.hashCode() == B.hashCode() : " + (A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()) );
   System.out.println("A == B : " + (A == B));
}

Comment: @user2321368 - That's a good point -- but YUCK!!! Maybe you can link to a gist or something instead of trying to put all that code inline with your comment.

Comment: Having the same hashcode doesnt mean equality since 2 equal objects NEED to have the same hashcode, but 2 different object DONT need to have a different hashcode. (hence hash collisions if you dont do a good enough hash function)

Comment: `==` for String objects performs a test for object identity as it compares the _memory addresses_ of the compared objects. _Hash code_ is a completely different concept. It is based on some operation on the contents at the specified address. _Hash codes_ comparison definitely evaluates to equal if _memory addresses_ are equal but **not** the other way round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. Since they are references to the same object, it's certain that they're equal.

```
String a = "foobar";
a.equals(a) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a `String` is a representation of a character array. When you call `.equals()` on that object, it will check each character in the array to see if they are the same while looping through.

The comparison at the beginning of `.equals()` checks to see if you are comparing it against the same object, that way if you are, the timing goes from being O(n) (with n being the size of the String in characters) to O(1).

Comment: Note that the same logic also applies to the `instanceof` check and the length comparison. Both of those are cheap checks that can give an _O(1)_ rather than having to compare every character.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about strings is that when they are created, they are kept in the heap for reuse.. so when you do this

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc"; //implicitly referencing same string object as a
a.equals(b); //true because of reference
a == b; //true because of reference
```

They are actually implicitly referencing at the same object within the heap.

unless you do this:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = new String("abc"); //explicitly creating a new string object
a.equals(b); //true because of value
a == b; //false because of reference
```